# Split column on first space after first comma

Tags: python, pandas

I have column like this:

```
     A B
1 000,00 2 000,00
1 400,00 2,00
1,00 2 000,00
```

I want to split it into two columns like this:

```
A           B 
1 000,00   2 000,00
1 400,00   2,00
1,00       2 000,00
```

I tried using spitting on space but it will wrongly split on first space:

```
df[["A", "B"]]=df["A B"].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

Instead I'm trying to split it on first space after first comma. Is it posible in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `extractall` then `unstack()`:

```
df[["A", "B"]] = df['A B'].str.extractall('([\d\s]*,[^\s]*)')[0].unstack()
```

Or this might be more fit to your logic (split by the first space after `,`):

```
df[['A','B']] = df['A B'].str.extract('([\d\s]*,[^\s]*) (.*)')
```

Output:

```
                 A B         A          B
0  1 000,00 2 000,00  1 000,00   2 000,00
1      1 400,00 2,00  1 400,00       2,00
2      1,00 2 000,00      1,00   2 000,00
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution here, with `split`

```
df[["A", "B"]]=df["A B"].str.split('(?<=,\d\d) ', 1, expand=True)
```

In the data you provided:

```
                 A B
0  1 000,00 2 000,00
1      1 400,00 2,00
2      1,00 2 000,00
```

There is another pattern that I used here, which is a `,` followed by 2 digits followed by the space we are targetting. Using this pattern, we can use look-behind `(?<=...)` to get our output

Output:

```
             A B         A         B
0  1 000,00 2 000,00  1 000,00  2 000,00
1      1 400,00 2,00  1 400,00      2,00
2      1,00 2 000,00      1,00  2 000,00
```

However, if the pattern I used above is not true in the entirety of your data, let me know.